How do we change the default location of pom.xml from the root directory to some other directory in an eclipse maven project?
I am working on a Maven project in which the 'pom.xml' resides in its default location (root directory of the project). This 'pom.xml' needs to be moved into another directory so that I can push it into Azure Repository, during my commits. How to achieve this ?
I am searching for the default folder location configuration of 'pom.xml' file in the maven project in eclipse. But, I'm unable to find it.

"This 'pom.xml' needs to be moved into another directory" sounds like the X of an XY problem. Please tell about the root problem (Y) that you want to solve by moving the POM to another directory.

Why is needed to move the pom to a different location? What is the real problem here?

Does Maven support doing this?

@khmarbaise When I commit my files in my eclipse, I want the pom.xml also to be moved into the Repository. And with the help of that pom.xml, I am planning to create a jar file using the pipeline. I have a directory in my eclipse where all the files inside it are getting pushed into the repository during a commit. But, the pom.xml falls outside this directory and hence it is not pushed

What other files do you have here? Usually a Maven project contains a pom.xml at the root level and other files are structured into default directory layout (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) for example: https://github.com/khmarbaise/smpp or other projects ... and no the pom file is part of the project and should be checked in ...

@khmarbaise I wanted to build the project inside an Azure DevOps Pipeline. So, I need to move this pom.xml into the repository. Since the pom.xml is at the root of the project, I am unable to move it into the repository.
